# Rounded corner radius for doughnut chart issue with stroke paint in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, paint, donut-chart

I have tried the following method to calculate a path to render doughnut charts with rounded corners, but it does not correctly work with stroke paint.

```
Path _getRoundedCornerArcPath(
num innerRadius,
num outerRadius,
Offset? center,
num startAngle,
num endAngle,
num? degree,
CornerStyle cornerStyle,
ChartPoint<dynamic> point) {
final Path path = Path();

Offset _midPoint;
num midStartAngle, midEndAngle;
if (cornerStyle == CornerStyle.startCurve ||
  cornerStyle == CornerStyle.bothCurve) {

  // Adding the rounded curve path by drawing circle
 _midPoint =
    _degreeToPoint(startAngle, (innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2, center!);
 midStartAngle = _degreesToRadians(180);
 midEndAngle = midStartAngle + _degreesToRadians(180);
 path.addArc(
    Rect.fromCircle(
        center: _midPoint, radius: (innerRadius - outerRadius).abs() / 2),
    midStartAngle.toDouble(),
    midEndAngle.toDouble());
}

// Adding the outer circle radius path
path.addArc(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: center!, radius: outerRadius.toDouble()),
  _degreesToRadians(startAngle).toDouble(),
  _degreesToRadians(endAngle - startAngle).toDouble());

 // Adding the inner circular radius path   
path.arcTo(
  Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: innerRadius.toDouble()),
  _degreesToRadians(endAngle.toDouble()).toDouble(),
  (_degreesToRadians(startAngle.toDouble()) -
          _degreesToRadians(endAngle.toDouble()))
      .toDouble(),
  false);

 return path;
}
```

**Issue with stroke paint**

[image]

**Works properly with fillpaint**

[image]

Can anyone suggest the way to achieve these rounded corners properly with stroke paint?

Answer (score 1):

change the strokeCap value of the Paint.

Example:

```
final paintArch = Paint();
paintArch.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).